# Why is Wordpress outputting phpinfo() when I try and go to a page?

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, redirect

I have just moved a Wordpress install from a remote host to run on my local development machine. On the remote server it's fully functional.

However, on my development box I can only load the homepage. Other URLs just load a standard `phpinfo()` page with no errors.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Talk about a needle in a haystack! Perhaps your .htaccess file? If you're using SEO friendly URLs then you'll need to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled and your .htaccess file is setup correctly.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry I can't give any more details up front!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using MAMP or WAMP on your dev box, which will load a default vhost showing phpinfo for any page that does not exist.

Inside wordpress, the settings, in the DB, it sounds like you have Url's "hardcoded" like "http://www.mysite.com" which are not working locally because your "dev" Url is something like "http://localhost"

Whenever using a development server, especially with wordpress, you should setup you dev server as close to your production server. This means you should edit your host file to make it so "http://www.mysite.com" actually goes to your development box or localhost. That way you are viewing everything as it will be when it goes to production.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well following the hosting company re-installing an SSL certificate.

I did some searching and really only found this thread which give me the idea there was a 404 error hiding there somewhere so I checked the php_errors.log file (which I found in the root folder of my site in FTP) - opened that in notepad and found many errors such as:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WordPressHTTPS_Module_phpinfo' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com.au/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-https/lib/Mvied/Plugin.php on line 385

So - indeed a missing file in the wordpress-https plugin.

To correct, I renamed the folder which contained that plugin (eg wp-content/plugins/wordpress-https  to wp-content/plugins/wordpress-https-disabled) - effectively disabling the plugin.

This then allowed me to login to the wordpress admin, install the latest version of that plugin - which worked fine and then deleted the old folder (wordpress-https-disabled)

Everyting was good as gold after that
Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

1. open httpd.conf in text editor
2. Change;

    AllowOveride none
3. To;
   AllowOveride All

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge when I cloned my remote site locally.

I fixed it by checking the .htaccess file and correcting this line to point to the right project folder:

```
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```